# Can not pipe the `pwd` result to tee

Tags: pipe, tee, pwd

I use Ubuntu 14.04. When i execute `ls | tee -` it works fine. But `pwd | tee -` just output absolute path only once and does not exit! i need to Ctrl+C to stop it.

[image: NEED to Ctrl+C to exit!]

Any clue?

EDIT:  I use bash.

Comment: What `does not work` mean?

Comment: What is your shell?

Comment: Can we assume that the plain `pwd` command works correctly?  Please try the following commands and post their results: `type pwd`, `pwd | cat`, `pwd | od -cb`, `"\pwd" | tee -`, and `(exec pwd) | tee -`.  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.  And please post the terminal output as text rather than as screen shots.  … … … … … … … … … … …  Wait — how are you posting screen shots?  You shouldn't have that privilege yet.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently using Ubuntu 14.04 and I have checked your command, "It was working for me!".

I guess the shell which you are using is different from mine.

Usually `tee` command will take the input from the standard input and throws the output to the standard output if we don't specify the input/output explicitly.

Comment: It would help if you mentioned which shell you are using too. ;-)

Comment: :) I am using bash shell.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, i made a mistake. i use bash, and i check my .bashrc, find `alias pwd='pwd && pwd | xclip'`. so the `pwd | tee -` actually turns into `pwd && pwd | xclip | tee -`. `pwd` give its output to `xclip` and `tee -` waits for input, that explains why the command does not exit.